# How to create a document for widgets(Flutter) and host it

Tags: flutter

The use case is that we are creating a package in Flutter, and we need to create a document widget, such as a README or Swagger documentation. How can we achieve this?

We've tried using the Mintlify plugin and 'dart doc' from the official Dart documentation, but we're not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

a. To create organized and user-friendly documentation, consider using a documentation generator tool like Dartdoc, Flutter Doc, or even Doxygen. These tools can generate HTML documentation from your source code comments.

b. You can add comments to your Flutter widget code using the '///' syntax, which is a standard Dart convention for documentation comments.

Next, use the selected documentation generator to generate HTML documentation from your code comments. Run the generator tool on your project directory, and it will create the necessary HTML files.

You need a platform or website where you can host your documentation. You can choose from various options:

- GitHub Pages: You can host your documentation on GitHub Pages for
  free. Create a GitHub repository for your documentation and push the
  generated HTML files to the repository. GitHub Pages will
  automatically serve your documentation as a website.
- Netlify: Netlify is a hosting service that makes it easy to deploy
  static websites, including documentation.
- GitLab Pages: Similar to GitHub Pages, GitLab provides hosting for
  static websites from GitLab repositories.
- Personal Website: If you have a personal website, you can host your
  documentation there.